# Rails attributes overriding

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Model with an attriubte "name". I would like to be able to create a getter "name" that returns name.capitalize.

The problem, however, is that when the model is saved, the capitalized name is being written to the database. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
def name
  attributes["name"].capitalize
end
```

and better to use another name for method

```
def capitalized_name # or "cap_name"
  name.capitalize
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def name
  read_attribute(:name).capitalize
end
```